# File not deleted from Downloads message (but got disappeared)

Tags: downloading, file-management, files, 8.1-oreo

When I try to delete a file using the downloads app (Android 8.1 app), I sometimes get the notification that my file couldn't be deleted and subsequent message by tapping the notification that my file wasn't deleted.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
 (click to enlarge)

But after this, the file is nowhere to be found in the downloads app, even when using a file explorer like Files Go or ES File explorer. I wonder what happened, whether my file got deleted or if not, then where is it?

I am using Nokia 3.1 Android version 8.1.0 Oreo. 
This problem has been there since my phone was new and had Android 8.0 Oreo.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Downloads app gives a list of all files that were downloaded - like a browser history. If the file was deleted already, it would still show up in the Downloads app even though the file doesn't exist any more. In that case, when you try to delete the file, the deletion will fail as you're seeing now.

This would happen if you deleted the file from the Downloads folder using a file explorer app (or some other app) instead of using the Downloads app, or if an app requested the download but deleted the file as soon as it finished using it.

This isn't the only explanation, but it's the most common one that fits your description.